# Assigning Command argument value to string in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:CheckBox oncheckedchanged="chk1_CheckedChanged" ID=chk1 CssClass='<%# Eval("UserID") + "," + Eval("IsB") %>' runat="Server"/>
```

I got this check box on my page..if I need to assign these two values of CommandArgument in CssClass attribute ie

<%# Eval("UserID") %> and <%# Eval("IsB") %> **to two strings** in my code behind..How do i do this ???

```
protected void chk1_OnCheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string s1 = "Need the first value from Command argument here";

string s2 = "Need the second value from Command argument here";
}
```

how do i fetch those command argument values passed in CssClass attribute of checkbox ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CssClass='<%# string.Format("{0},{1}", Eval("UserID"), Eval("IsB")) %>'
```

And in your code behind:

```
protected void chk1_OnCheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    var tokens = chk.CssClass.Split(',');  
    string userId = tokens[0];
    string isB = tokens[1];
}
```

Comment: Its giving me this error ...The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: changed it to this var tokens = chk.CssClass.Split(new char[] { ',' });

Comment: @Serenity, sorry I made a typo in my code. It should be a char literal and not string literal: `.Split(',')`.